# Do chain attacks benefit from damage boosts when the art is based on position?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

Arts like [Edge Trust](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Edge_Thrust) and [Hammerhead](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Hammerhead_(XC3)) inflict extra damage based on your position when attacking the enemy, that being back strike and side strike respectively.

When performing a chain attack, my units will sometimes be in the correct position to where the art that is being performed would normally receive a boost. Do these types of arts receive damage boosts based on your position during chain attacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they do. One of the easiest ways to test this is with an un-broken enemy, using a Side Break art (which will only trigger when you break from the side). No matter where your character is positioned, the break *can* trigger.